# structures corresponding to metastable states in python

Tags: python, data-analysis, biopython, hidden-markov-models, mdanalysis

I have a question, I currently have a Markov state model with 4 metastable states, what I would like is to find the structures corresponding to those metastable states in python.

Comment: guess they'll be hidden

Comment: find the local  nimums has per https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7314396/figure/pro3859-fig-0001/